# React - history.location.state complains about a wrong type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a link that passes the current url to the next route.

```
    <Link to={{ pathname: `/cars/tesla/${row.id}`, state: { prevPath: location.pathname } }}>
```

In the next route I'm trying to use the previous URL:

```
props.history.location.state?.prevPath ? props.history.goBack() : props.history.push('/cars/search')
```

but I get a type error:

[image]

How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue before. It dues to a change in the latest version of types/history. A workaround is to downgrade the version of types/history

```
npm install @types/history@4.7.3 --save-dev
```

You can find more detail about this issue here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674

Answer (score 1):

This is because `history.location.state` is a dynamic param you can pass when you navigate throught `<Link>` or `history.push`.

By default `@types/react-router` type `history.location.state` as an empty object.
So you probably want to either

```
props.history.location.(state as any)?.prevPath 
  ? props.history.goBack() 
  : props.history.push('/')
```

Or using `useHistory` you can use generic type:

```
const history = useHistory<{ prevPath: string }>()

history.location.state?.prevPath 
  ? props.history.goBack() 
  : props.history.push('/')
```